# I can't stop bootstrap from stacking horizontally placed div's

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a header which consists of an image of span 7 then a search bar and finally I'm going to add some social media icons. But the problem I'm running into is that my search bar moves below my image when i decrease the size of the browser. I don't want this to happen, I just want the image and search bar and the icons to decrease size proportionally.

```
<div class="navbar-static-top">
    <div class="navbar-inner">
        <div class="row-fluid">
            <div class="span7">
                <a href= "#"><img src="img/image1.png" alt="image alt"></a>
            </div>
            <div class="span3">
                <form class="navbar-search pull-left">
                    <input type="text" class="search-query"  placeholder="Search..."/>
                </form>
            </div>
            <div class="span2">
                <!-- Social media icons will be added later -->
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You have `row-fluid` - read about what it does: http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/scaffolding.html#gridSystem

Comment: Try setting the size of the textbox to width:100%

Comment: I started a fiddle for you.. http://jsfiddle.net/PR3zq/ Can you try to reproduce the problem with your css? Cause it appears to work as expected here.

Comment: @NickR , nope I've already tried changing it to row, doesn't work.

Comment: @Kyle that doesn't work either.

Comment: @KrisHollenbeck well i haven't added any CSS to it yet, i'm only using  bootsrap's inbuilt classes.

Comment: Okay, is the fiddle example what you are looking for? Cause that is only using bootstrap CSS and it appears to be the result you are looking for.

Comment: Here is another demo with an Icon... http://jsfiddle.net/PR3zq/1/

Answer (score 0):

```
@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .no-responsive [class*="span"] {
    float: left !important;
  }
  .no-responsive .span7 {
    width: 57.18232044198895% !important;
    *width: 57.12912895262725% !important;
  }
  .no-responsive .span3 {
    width: 22.92817679558011% !important;
    *width: 22.87498530621841% !important;
  }
  .no-responsive .span2 {
    width: 14.3646408839779% !important;
    *width: 14.311449394616199% !important;
  }
}
```

change `<div class="row-fluid">` to `<div class="row-fluid no-responsive">`
and use `.input-block-level` class for your search

Comment: Still not happening, anyways in need bootstrap-responsive.css for other parts of my webpage.

Comment: You might need to tweak it a bit but it should get you going in the right direction.